# Python - how to get histogram plot as in R?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plot

A simple example:

```
> v <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5)
> names(v) <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> v
  1   2   3   4   5 
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 
> plot(v,type='h')
```

that yields

[image]

I am struggling to get the exact same plot with python. Using matplotlib histogram it does not plot the index. (whereas R seems to)

Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually want a histogram because your values are already histogrammed data.

Instead you may use a barplot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]

plt.bar(range(len(v)), v)

plt.show()
```

[image]

In order to get lines instead of bars, you may set the bar width to 0

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]

plt.bar(range(len(v)), v, width=0, ec="k")

plt.show()
```

[image]